# How do I switch Auto Perspective on?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I recently had an issue with Blender 2.71 RC2, which I submitted as a bug. The issue was that when I hit <kbd>Numpad</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>7</kbd> the viewport would not automatically change from perspective  to orthographic  mode, as it used to in Blender 2.70.

I now want it to behave like this in blender 2.71 RC2, but I can't find the **Auto Perspective** check box in the user preferences.

Where is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is in the *Interface*> *View Manipulation* section:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.80, it is now under Navigation > Orbit & Pan[image: Blender Preferences showing the Navigation tab on the left and the Orbit & Pan tab on the right with Auto Perspective circled and unchecked]