# Views (Front, Back, Right and Left) have been altered and added perspective

Tags: 3d-view

This has happened once I've used Shift+C, for when I needed my 3D cursor to get back to the origin. So that, for the Front view I get:
[image: Not perpendicular to the Z axis...]

Instead of what I get when I open a new file:

[image: Perpendicular to the Z axis]

Anyone has a clue of what is causing this?

/Ivan

Comment: Perspective has a vanishing point.  Your second screen shot is directly in line with the cube, and hence you only see the front face. Ctrl 8 or 2 (on numeric keypad) will show this.  Ortho (5 turns on off) is the view to use for plan view.  (Hitting period "." on numeric keypad with object selected will give you direct view for axis aligned objects)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86969/how-do-i-change-the-mode-of-perspective, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/how-do-i-switch-auto-perspective-on